# How to create a table with multiple rows in one row (Material-UI/CSS)

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, html-table, material-ui

I have the array like this :

```
const sample = [
  { name: 'apple', detail: [{'a', 'b'}]},
  { name: 'banana', detail: [{'a', 'b'}]},
];
```

Let's say I want to create a table looks like the following attachment:

[image]

That's the table body part, and I have put all the details in  inside of . It's creating the table as I expected but the size is really narrow and also doesn't match with the table head.

I was wondering if there's a smart way to have **map multiple data in a row and embed in one table cell.**

**The name part (which are apple and banana) must be the first table cell with row span.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that using rowSpan on your `TableCell`. Just assign it a value of `detail.length + 1`

Here, give this a try:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    overflowX: "auto"
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 700
  }
}));

const sample = [
  { name: "apple", detail: ["a", "b", "c", "d"] },
  { name: "banana", detail: ["a", "b"] }
];

export default function SpanningTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Table className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Fruit</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Buyers</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {sample.map(item => (
            <Fragment>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell rowSpan={item.detail.length + 1}>
                  {item.name}
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              {item.detail.map(detail => (
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>{detail}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </Fragment>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-demo-with-row-span-dq1w6) Demo for your ref.

Comment: This has a problem if there are w few rows that has only one item and not many... a blank space is shown